Waldtest:Error in modelCompare(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]], vfun = vcov0) : nesting of models cannot be determined
I hope that someone can help me with the following problem with Waldtest and robustlmm package. I want to compare two robust regression models. I want to test whether one of the following nested models fits significantly better than the other (the Waldtest is the only possibility to do such a comparison with rlmer-models, as far as I know):
HVLT_rlmer_0 <- rlmer(hvlt_r ~ 1 + (1|ID), data = data)
HVLT_rlmer_mod <- rlmer(hvlt_r ~ event_name + intervention + 
event_name*intervention + (1|ID), data = data)

Although the models are nested, the following error message occurs:
waldtest(HVLT_rlmer_mod, HVLT_rlmer_0)
Waldtest:Error in modelCompare(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]], 
vfun = vcov0) :    nesting of models cannot be determined

Does someone know how I can solve this problem?

Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. I flagged the question as off-topic but it was declined (I still think it is). But since it's going to stay here, please add a reproducible example for people to work with. Without such a reproducible example, my guess is that the samples are different due to missingness, etc.

The issue might be much more simple btw. Have you checked whether waldtest supports rlmer or not?
